# Dot Net core MVC 7 Identity Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, asp.net-core-7.0

I am Implementing Identity in Dot Net core MVC 7. [This is the tutorial I was Following](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhCstGA9WVI&t=193s&ab_channel=RavindraDevrani). Then Suddenly Error Came
Error Came

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'LearnIdentity.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.RegisterModel'.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, bool isDefaultParameterRequired)
```

I tried re-watching video again and again. Tried chat GTP. Unable to relsove please help me
[Click here for Source code](https://github.com/Ayazhaider7786/Dot-Net-Core-7-Identity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download your repo and reproduce the issue in my side when click the login button.

Error

[image]

Then I check the `Program.cs` file and `login.cshtml`, `login.cshtml.cs` file. You are using `ApplicationUser` in `Program.cs`  and  using `IdentityUser` in `login.cshtml.cs`.

The solution is using `ApplicationUser` in `login.cshtml.cs`. And the issue will be fixed. And please don't forget add `using LearnIdentity.Data;` in `login.cshtml.cs`

[image]

It works in my side

[image]